# Why in ESXi is the file size of a thin provisioned virtual disk the same size as the real disk?

Tags: esxi

When I create in ESXi (version 7.0.3) the following 3 virtual disks...
1) 10 GB / thin provisioned
2) 10 GB / thick provisioned, lazily zeroed
3) 10 GB / thick provisioned, eagerly zeroed
...all files (*-flat.vmdk) have the same size:
-rw------- 1 root root 10737418240 Oct 16 18:09 TEST_1-flat.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root         479 Oct 16 18:09 TEST_1.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root 10737418240 Oct 16 18:10 TEST_2-flat.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root         455 Oct 16 18:10 TEST_2.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root 10737418240 Oct 16 18:10 TEST_3-flat.vmdk
-rw------- 1 root root         455 Oct 16 18:11 TEST_3.vmdk

Shouldn't the thin provisioned virtual disk (TEST_1-flat.vmdk) be much smaller so we can easily copy it away as a backup?

Comment: did you format the disk?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/608286/vmware-esxi-5-5-thin-provision-still-allocates-full-amount-of-space-on-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re looking at a Linux sparse file. It’s a file that the operating system knows is a certain size but doesn’t actually take up that much physical space. It’s full of holes.

Try `ls -ls` to display the physical disk usage as well as the logical disk usage.

Any attempt to manipulate the file, like copying it directly to another disk is going to give you the full file size and not the smaller, physical usage. Whatever tool you use, it must work with sparse files.

Comment: vCenter and/or Workstation will allow you to determine the real size of virtual HDD for the VM.

Comment: So there's no possibility, as for example with VMware Workstation, to save the virtual disk file only in the effective size, but the file must always be saved in the full size?

Comment: @Michi your question was about ESXi which is Linux based. And this is how it works. I don’t know how workstation works, especially on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, my question is about ESXi. But I still wonder where the sense is here, because if I want to backup this file, I've to backup the complete large file (e.g. to my USB hard disk). But I want to backup only the effective data. Is there really no way to compact these thin provisioned virtual disks to the effectively used size.

Comment: @Michi it’s a function of the operating system and it’s how it’s done on Linux. You can back the file up but you need to use a tool/product that supports sparse files. You can look in to `tar —sparse`